# AWK to filter a file based upon columns of another file

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I have two files.  The first file looks like this (but is thousands of lines long:

```
Chr10:2-20 0 0 0 0
Chr1:390-32032 1 2 0 0 
Chr3:32-3020 0 0 1029 20
Chr4:30239-40000 10 15 10 20
Chr10:2-20 9 9 1 8
Chr7:0-80 1 0 3 9
Chr8:0-30 8 6 3 3
```

The second file looks like this (but is also thousands of lines long)

```
Chr1:390-32032
Chr4:30239-40000
Chr3:32-3020
....
Chr4:30239-40000
```

I want to produce a third file, that pulls data from the first file, only if that Chr record is in the second one.  So the third file would look like this:

```
Chr1:390-32032 1 2 0 0 
Chr4:30239-40000 10 15 10 20
Chr3:32-3020 0 0 1029 20
Chr4:30239-40000 10 15 10 20
```

The idea I have had for the code was to use AWK, and the fnr==nr function.  Possibly put the first columns into arrays?  I just cant seem to get things to work properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: See [Select lines from text file which have ids listed in another file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110645/select-lines-from-text-file-which-have-ids-listed-in-another-file?noredirect=1&lq=1) for a solution using *grep*. You will just have to cut the ID values out of the second file (use the *cut* command) to use for indexing. No need for *awk* for this task.

Comment: Thanks Simon!  I actually won't need to use cut, as I'll still want that first column in the new file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below awk construct should be able to do what you are looking for.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1][$0];next} $0 in a {for (i in a[$0]) print i}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Where :

`a[$1]` : During file1 pass, create an 2D array `a` with 1st column($1) and whole line($0) of file1.

`$0 in a` : During file2 pass, check for entire line($0) of file2 exists in 1st index of array `a`

`{for (i in a[$0]) print i}` : If it exists, scan the subarray and print the value. This value will be $0 of first file.

Comment: Any specific reason why the answer was downvoted ? I will try to rectify it.

Comment: Hey, it shouldn't have been downvoted - it works great and it's faster than using grep!  Thanks a ton!!