# Use awk to remove lines based on a column from another file

Tags: awk

I have the following code that works to extract lines from the multiple-column file_1 that have a value in the first column that appears in the single-column file_2:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1][$0];next} $0 in a {for (i in a[$0]) print i}' file_1 file_2
```

I got this code from the answer to this question: [AWK to filter a file based upon columns of another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51645744/awk-to-filter-a-file-based-upon-columns-of-another-file)

I want to change to code to do the opposite, namely to remove every line from file_1 where the first column matches any value that appears in the single-column file_2. How do I do this?

Comment: consider updating the question with some sample input data, the (wrong) output generated by your code, and the (correct) expected output

Comment: This is by far the most frequently asked question on this forum, it gets asked once or twice a week, please just take a look in the archives. See for example the script in this comment from a few hours earlier - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69398623/comparing-strings-between-files-with-awk-when-the-strings-use-special-character#comment122661963_69398623

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR { arr[$0]="1";next  } arr[$1]!="1" { print $0 }' file2 file1
```

Process the second file first (NR==FNR) and create an array called arr, with the line ($0) as the key and 1 the value. Then when processing the next file (file1), check if the first space delimited field ($1) exists as a key in the array arr and if it doesn't, print the line.

Direct the output to a file if you want to store the results:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { arr[$0]="1";next  } arr[$1]!="1" { print $0 }' file2 file1 > file3
```

Comment: While that will produce the expected output, it's using more memory and execution time than necessary to do so (would be particularly bad if `file1` was large) and it's unnecessarily hard-coding default instructions.